# How to interact with USB filesystem cache?

Tags: windows, powershell, caching, usb

I would like to know how USB drives are handled in Windows. Upon inserting a USB drive, I understand that the USB filesystem is cached. But I want to be able to interact with the cached filesystem (i.e. delete/reset the cache) programmatically. Can someone point me in the right direction to understanding how Windows caches USB filesystems and how to interact with it?

I haven't been able to find documentation describing how USB filesystems are cached.

Comment: The driver makes the USB interface look like a File System.  The cache is inside the driver.  Check the driver documentation you are using.  Is the drive a smart card?  Smart cards have two drivers one for the holder and one for the card.

Comment: @jdweng Nothing special, just an ordinary USB stick plugged into ny laptop through a USB 3.0 slot running Windows 10. So I'm assuming the default USB drivers Windows uses. Any idea where I would go about finding the docs for these drivers? Appreciate the help

Comment: @AMAlonso64 you cannot interact with the USB cache directly. What you are looking for is to use APIs specifically made for that purpose (manufactuer) or Windows Driver Model (WDM) or a Windows Storage Management API (SMAPI). This even goes above my head!